# truncated question mark during login by ouath 3 with facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, oauth, angular6

Hi I've implemented in my application with Angular 6 + Laravel authentication user by facebook. I redirect the page to facebook dialog with confirmation user by change href windows object:

```
window.location.href = `https://www.facebook.com/v3.1/dialog/oauth?client_id=${appId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&response_type=token&display=popup&state={st=${stateParam}}`;
```

After I've confirmed the authentication there is a redirection to url with question mark for a a few hundred milliseconds(on the localhost):

```
http://localhost:4200/facebook-token?#state=%7Bst%3Dcar_workshop%7D&access_token=EAAdmi6KgztwBABnt4CxRLBg8yZBgtrSNX6paMeAauPIt7iZC4MSjgTDnf5ZCCvSg0HmowYk2SkLtRmKnz6KNlt6ayZCRR6ZCoZBHmsE9LLAx7NSDKS3CD3pdEEgZCgy7NBY9suArgePT8RYF6ph5P1uqZBq1PkSfBWISLgzymeKZCQ5l2apLZAVckRw35Xl8ihMkkZD&expires_in=5814&reauthorize_required_in=7776000&data_access_expiration_time=1548278586
```

and after that the question mark is **truncated** from url an it looks like:

```
http://localhost:4200/facebook-token#state=%7Bst=car_workshop%7D&access_token=EAAdmi6KgztwBAAEFhbHIxSQR42WE7jJWUFjjxqIZAT1bsX62bgjNAIkh77PyK5ZCfcHZAoOkM1XhjDNukl1EJeJKXYZBftTlpzQk5dWXtvZAORUZCWStuYwWI2gkkNFtBkdDK5kAzZAsgGtjI0FONpvZCsd9fbQWTEqMnZBiHdIk4VTT5dFrBLZBcPTM9W1ZCZBPUI4ZD&expires_in=5655&reauthorize_required_in=7776000&data_access_expiration_time=1548278745
```

Then it is processed by component in routing module:

```
path: 'facebook-token',
        component: FacebookTokenComponent
```

Next an AJAX request is sent to backend and authentication is confirmed.

In my opinion truntacted which I've describted above is not very nice for the eye. Is there any possible way to skip the step with truncation of question mark in URL? Is this a problem on the Angular6 or Facebook api side? I would be greateful for the answers
Best regards

Comment: What is the exact redirect URI value you pass to the dialog?

Comment: I thing it dosen't matter beacuese it is something with Router angular Component, but I don't know how change that.